# Twitter for HTC Sense claims multiple accounts are not supported

Tags: htc-sense, twitter

I deleted internet data and other data to get more space on my internal memory. Now Twitter for HTC Sense will not work again and keeps telling me "multiple accounts are not supported". I do not have multiple accounts. But I can't get into this app to change anything. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

You could always clear the data for the app, if the app is simply kicking you out when you open it.

Go to Settings -> Applications -> Manage applications. Select your app, and click Clear Data. This will wipe all data from the app, as if you had uninstalled it and installed it fresh*.

*To be technical, it isn't the same as uninstalling and reinstalling because the dex files in the Dalvik Cache remain unchanged. Installing a fresh copy would regenerate those files. But it really shouldn't matter for non-developers.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I checked the application and it has already been cleared, since then I am having this problem. The widget 'Twitter for HTC Sense' will not open but instead gives this message about multiple accounts. If I try Peep, the app which is also on this smartphone, it says the same thing. But I do not know where to 'unsign' in case of 'multiple accounts'.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I used friend-stream to get the notification from Twitter and Facebook. After I cleared the data of internet, Peep did not work. But today, I deleted the Peep account in Friend stream, Peep recovered.

I hope this information may help you.

Comment: Is friend-stream an app? If yes, please add a link. :)

Comment: friend stream is one of the widgets in HTC.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem.  Just solved it.

1. Delete the widget
2. Go to `Settings > Accounts & sync`
3. Delete the "Twitter for HTC Sense" account
4. Add the widget
5. Breathe a sigh of relief